# Django doesn't see view

Tags: django, django-views

In my urls.py I have the followwing:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    #url(r'^$', 'welcome_page.home', name='home'),
    #url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^welcome_page/$', include('OnePK_Web.views.welcome_page')),

    )
```

Where views is a package with module welcome_page

When I am trying to run I have the following : The included urlconf  doesn't have any patterns in it.

I don't understand how to fix it. Any Ideas?

Comment: What's in your welcome_page.py? Does it have url patterns in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$` from the following pattern if `OnePK_Web.views.welcome_page` is `app` name:

```
url(r'^welcome_page/$', include('OnePK_Web.views.welcome_page')),
#                   ^
```

If `OnePK_Web.views.welcome_page` is a view name, remove `include(..)`:

```
url(r'^welcome_page/$', 'OnePK_Web.views.welcome_page')
```

Comment: if I use views.py what should be instead of 'OnePK_Web.views.welcome_page' ?

Comment: @user2970627, `views.welcome_page` if `views.py` is at the same directory with `urls.py`. Or `<directory-name-that-contains-views.py>.views.welcome_page`; make sure `welcome_page` function in the `views.py`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to an app view through your "PROJECT URLs" refer to following syntax:

```
    url(r'^welcome_page/$','appname.views.viewnameforthisurl',name='viewnameforthisurl'),
```

If you are reffering to views corresponding to your "APP URLs" through your "PROJECT URLs" refer to following syntax:

```
    url(r'^welcome_page/$',include('appname.urls')),
```

else if your struck in the app urls, Try reading djangoproject documentation. For every django related problem, you will find an appropriate and logical way out